# How to more efficiently use Tortoise SVN diff for large Excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel, tortoise-svn

I was pleasantly surprised to find that Tortoise SVN diff lets me find the diff between two excel files. The cell which is different is highlighted in red. It works for small excel files.

But I have Excel sheets which have thousands of rows and quite a few columns.

Is there a way to quickly find the cells that have changed (as opposed to scrolling through each sheet slowly and finding the highlighted cells, which is time-consuming and error-prone)?

Answer (score 0):

To use this with Tortoise Diff you will need to export them both to CSV and diff the files, not the most ideal but helpful. If you have  [Office Professional Plus 2013 or Office 365 ProPlus](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-spreadsheet-compare-0e1627fd-ce14-4c33-9ab1-8ea82c6a5a7e) you can use Excel Compare feature. There are other methods, which would likely be unwieldy with such large files, and third party tools, [described here.](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/02/25/compare-two-excel-files-sheets/)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an adaptation of the [these instructions](https://www.programmersought.com/article/1042867681/) that show how to replace TortoiseSVN’s diff operation for Excel spreadsheets with the Microsoft Office “[Spreadsheet Compare” utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-spreadsheet-compare-0e1627fd-ce14-4c33-9ab1-8ea82c6a5a7e) that comes with Office Professional Plus 2013, Office Professional Plus 2016, Office Professional Plus 2019, or Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise. (Spreadsheet Compare compares *all worksheets* in two workbooks.)

1. Create the following batch script. I named it `sc.bat` and stored it in

   **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\DCF`**

   alongside the `SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE` executable. (If you don’t have permission
   to write to that directory, store it somewhere else, in which case you’ll need
   to change the `%~dp0` on line 5 of `sc.bat` to point to the above directory).
   Note that the two filenames `%~1` and `%~2` MUST be on separate lines of
   the text file, unquoted.)

> ```
> @echo off
> set SCTEMP="%TEMP%\sctemp~%RANDOM%.txt"
> echo %~1 > "%SCTEMP%"
> echo %~2 >> "%SCTEMP%"
> "%~dp0\SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE" "%SCTEMP%"
> ```

2. Open the TortoiseSVN settings window (right-click on any directory –> TortoiseSVN –> Settings), select "Difference Viewer" on the left, and click the "Advanced Settings" button on the right:
   [image: TortoiseSVN Settings Dialog]
3. In the Advanced Difference Comparison Settings dialog that opens, go to the `.xlsx` extension, click on [Edit], and enter the following command (change the directory if you didn’t store `sc.bat` in the directory with `SPREADSHEETCOMPARE.EXE`):

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\DCF\sc.bat %base %mine
> ```

Click [OK] on three dialog boxes to get all the way out.

From this point on, when you use TortoiseSVN to compare a file (e.g. right-click on it and select “diff”, or double-click on it during a Commit dialog), you will pull up Microsoft’s Spreadsheet Compare utility.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: if you can store your spreadsheets in a text-based format -- e.g. [`.fods`](https://docs.fileformat.com/spreadsheet/fods) -- the default diff tool will suffice.